# How to calculate revenue by month between years in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The columns in the below dataset will represent:

A: Date contract opened;

B: Date contract stops;

C: Unique account ID against which contract associated (can have multiple contracts live against one ID)

D: Monthly revenue for contract period - for simplicity, assume revenue generated from first month contract assumed up to month before the date the contract closes

```
Start Date  contract end date   Unique Account Field            MRR
1/2/2013         1/2/2015                 50e55                 195.00
1/2/2013         1/2/2014                 4ee75                 50.00
1/2/2013         1/2/2014                 4f031                 75.00
1/2/2013         1/2/2016                 4c3b2                 133.00
1/2/2013         1/2/2016                 49ec8                 132.00
1/3/2013         1/3/2014                 49fc8                 59.00
1/4/2013         1/4/2015                 49wc8                 87.00
12/27/2013       12/27/2014               50bf7                 190.00
12/27/2013       12/27/2014               49cc8                 179.00
12/27/2013       12/27/2014               49wc8                 147.00
etc....
```

I would like to calculate the following:

1.How much revenue was generated by month between Jan-2013 and Dec-2014?

2.How many active contracts (generated revenue in that month) were there by month between Jan-2013 and Dec-2014?

3.How many active accounts (generated revenue from at least one contract) were there by month between Jan-2013 and Dec-2014?

I tried the below code: I was able to use sum() to get the revenues, but I'm not sure what to do beyond this.

```
from datetime import date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])    
df.groupby(df['Start Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['MRR'].sum().sort_values()
```

Result I got from the above code:

```
Start Date
February     221744
January      241268
July         245811
August       247413
April        249702
March        251219
June         251494
May          259149
September    263395
October      293990
November     296590
December     311659
```

I need to calculate the above following. How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: Is the contract end date relevant for any of the calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
date_range = (df['date'] >= "2013-01-01") & (df['date'] <= "2014-12-31")
df[date_range].groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%B')).agg(
    MRR=('MRR', 'sum'),
    Contracts=('date', 'count'),
    Accounts=('Unique Account Field', 'nunique')
)
```

Output :-

```
            MRR   Contracts Accounts
date            
December    516.0  3        3
January     731.0  7        7
```

Comment: Thanks much! @fibonachoceres I will try with my actual dataset